# Bayesian update with multiple parameters

Tags: bayesian, estimation, joint-distribution

In the past I have been able to do Bayesian updating when there is just one parameter which I am trying to estimate. I know a bit about Bayesian methods but I am confused by how to extend them to multiple parameters.

One parameter is X which can take the values $[x_1, x_2, x_3]$ They have a prior probability $[0.2, 0.2, 0.6]$

The other parameter in the model is Y which can take the values $[y_1, y_2, y_3]$ with a prior probability $[0.1, 0.5, 0.4]$

There are two ways I see of treating this problem and I'm not sure which is correct.

Method 1.

I treat the problem by updating both parameters together so that there are 9 states which the parameters can take (any combination of X and Y values). If E is the evidence, $P(x,y)$ is the prior probability of x and y, and $P^*(x,y)$ is the posterior probability of x and y then

$P^*(x_1,y_1)= \frac{P(x_1,y_1) P(E|x_1,y_1)}{P(E)}$

Method 2.

I treat the problem by updating each parameter individually. In this case I have to consider the probability of the evidence given $x_i$ and any value of Y so I sum all terms over Y.

$P^*(x_1)= \frac{P(x_1) \sum_{j=1}^3 P(E|x_1, y_j)}{P(E)}$

And I use a similar approach for updating probabilities of y

Both of these methods have downsides, I am not sure if both are correct. Could someone shed some light on which of these is normally used?

Comment: Presumably you have assumed $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Considering the case where they are not independent might illuminate the situation for you.

Comment: @whuber thanks a lot, I think I've got it now! Honestly I prefer these type of answers more because they get me to think about the problem and understand it more